# How to dissolve faces using geo nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is this currently possible using geo nodes?

[image: Face Selection]
[image: Desired Outcome]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no node in *Geometry Nodes* that is comparable to the function "Dissolve Faces".

You can only delete single vertices, edges or faces via a selection.

You can do this either by selecting by index, or by using a vertex group.

As it looks on your picture, you prefer a selection via a vertex group.

This way you can easily remove the desired faces or edges. But deleting the edges always removes the faces.

Therefore it is a bit more complex to build "Dissolve Faces" in *Geometry Nodes*:

[image]

Here I first split the mesh into two parts. One part contains the selected faces.

I convert these into curves, because this makes them available as separate splines.

At the same time I create a new curve, which I multiply according to the number of splines.

These curves are then divided according to the number of points of the original splines and closed with `Fill Curve`. This gives me new faces whose points along the outer edge correspond to the previously selected faces.

Finally I just move the points of this mesh to the original position of the removed faces and close the mesh again with `Merge by Distance`.

[image]

Comment: One disadvantage of creating new geometry and then merging that in (Merge by distance) is that Vertex Group values are 1/2 the original values for merged verticies (unfortunately there is also no "max" Mode for the Vertex group interpolation for Merge by dist./Weld)

Comment: @Patter Unfortunately, this is correct. However, you could transfer the required attributes to the newly created geometry with `Sample Nearest` (or `Transfer Attributes`) beforehand. This way no interpolation of the values would take place.

Comment: Using that nice approach for a mesh with many holes to fill, I realized how painfully slow `Fill Curve` especially in `N-gons` mode is. For whatever reason it also consumes crazy amounts of memory. So I pimped your node group a bit by directly creating filled triangles and squares (`Mesh Circle` with `Fill Type=N-gon`) for the special cases of holes with 3 and 4 corners (which I'm mostly interested in). This turns out to be orders of magnitude faster and doesn't consume much memory.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! For holes with a known number of points, this is of course a good option. But if the holes have a variable number of points, I'm afraid there's no way around `Fill Curve`.

Comment: True. My special version still works for arbitrary numbers of vertices but it first separates curves with 3 and then 4 points before falling back to the `Fill Curve` node for the remaining curves. In my case I tried with ~6200 4-corner holes and that was running for several minutes before I terminated Blender because it filled up my memory (was already >>64GB). With the pimped version it took about 10ms and I did not see any significantly increased memory consumption. So I think the `Fill Curve` node has some room for optimizations ;-)

Comment: Hello, I tried tweaking this setup so it dissolves faces not by vertex group but by edge angle, so I plugged Edge Angle to math node, set angle threshold and plugged to Separate Geometry node instead of Capture Attribute, but only the middle faces got dissolved, not the rim faces. I suppose it's because it's looking for faces that meet the angle criteria with all their edges, so like, it considers faces as whole, not the individual edges like I wished for. It there a way to dissolve ALL edges that meet the angle criteria?

Answer (score 0):

if you know the indices, you can do it like this:

[image]