Dissolve vertices in Geometry Node?
Is there any way to dissolve vertices in Geometry Node?
In my case I want to dissolve that vertices not deleting.

EDIT:
I checked this thread but this doesn't work for vertices
i understand there's no native way to dissolve vertices,
but i think it has the same approach by merging the vertices to the closed corner but i don't know how to do it.

Hello no there is no way to dissolve vertices in Geometry Nodes. You could maybe try something similar to this here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270982/how-to-dissolve-faces-using-geo-nodes

Hi, that method is use fill curve its intended for face not for vertices,
that nodes setup only re fill the face using fill curve which is not related with floating vertices

Thanks for checking. Well unfortunately there is no Geometry Nodes node for dissolving vertices.

yeah, i edited the question.
hopefully someone know if there is another workaround e.g by merging to the corner face.
thanks for your reespond anyway :)

You might consider creating a setup that identifies the vertices forming a face, removes them, and then fills back in the face.

the linked quellenform's method is pretty much the approach you would use here, except you don't need to select a boundary across multiple faces, just convert a single face to a curve. Or skip that entirely: face corners should be ordered in a counter-clockwise fashion (looking from the front of the face), so you can just spawn a mesh circle and put it onto that face (skipping the verts you want to dissolve).

just tried quellenform's method and i adjust it to mimic dissolve vertice.
but i can't achieve it with my basic knowledge with GN.
if you think using quellenform's method can dissolve vertice on my case above, could you please elaborate it as answer?.
and i think its more eficient by moving the desired vertices to the corner of face, and merge it.
but i don't know how to do it :(
